# RubyMotion: UIWindow backgroundColor

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I'm watching this introductory screencast on RubyMotion to get started http://pragmaticstudio.com/screencasts/rubymotion. In the screencast, the author uses window.backgroundColor to set the background color. However, when I look into the UIWindow class reference on this page http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006817, I don't see a backgroundColor property. Where does this come from? Can anyone help please?

Comment: Never mind, I just figured out that since UIWindow inherits from UIView, it also inherits the backgroundColor property.

Comment: Then post that as an answer to your question to get it off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

(This is just what the asker said solved his problem -- I just wanted this question to get off the Unanswered page)

The solution, as posted by the asker, is:

> Never mind, I just figured out that since UIWindow inherits from
>   UIView, it also inherits the backgroundColor property.